# GET key change how to show what is in the url

Tags: php, get

I want to display everything what is in a url.

So if someone use `test.php?test=yes&no=why`

i want to show

```
test = yes
no = why
```

but when someone use `test.php?bla=blala`

i want to show

```
bla = blala
```

Is this possible?

Comment: have you at least TRIED to google "print array php" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . " = " . $value
}
```

Comment: Without a line break it will be difficult to see where the values end and the keys start.

Comment: You can easily edit output message. Most important is how to get needed data.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty print the `$_GET` variable.

`<?php print_r($_GET); ?>`

Answer (score 2):

use this php script:

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value){
    echo $key . " = " . $value;
}
```

Comment: Without a line break it will be difficult to see where the values end and the keys start.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php var_dump( $_GET ); ?>
```

will echo out everything inside $_GET

```
<?php var_dump( $_REQUEST ); ?>
```

will do everything in both a $_POST and an $_GET

You can also try

```
<?php
  $string = "Url Variables <br />";
  foreach( $_REQUEST as $key => $value ){
     $string .= $key." = ".$value." <br />";
  }

  echo $string;
?>
```